# js regex get characters after the match

Tags: javascript, regex

I got the code like this:

```
let first = "filename=awesome;blabla";

let second = first.match("/filename=(.*)/");

console.log(second);
```

I want to get **awesome** in **second** string.

So my regex is not fully correct as it gives me **awesome;blabla**

how do I get only "**awesome**" in second string?

Comment: remove the quotes `"` , you're trying to match the regex string , try `let [,second] = first.match(/filename=(.*)/);`

Comment: thanks so much. how did I miss that? could you help me with one more thing? i will update the question.

Comment: you want the regex to be `/filename=(.*?);/` if you only want to capture up to the semicolon

Comment: `/filename=(.+?);/` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your are passing the regex as String so you should remove quotes:

```
let second = first.match(/filename=(.*)/);
```

Also, according with [match function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) the result is an array where the first element is the complete match and the rest of elements its related capturing groups. So your group will be in the second element:

```
console.log(second[1]);
```

Also you have to modify your regex in order to get just the chars before the ';':

```
let first = "filename=awesome;blabla";

let second = first.match(/filename=([^;]*);/);

console.log(second[1]);
```

Comment: could you take a look? i updated the question.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I see, I've just modified my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
first.match(/filename=([^;]+)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
const reg2 = /filename=(.*)/;

const url = 'filename=awesome';
const id = url.match(reg2)[1];

console.log(id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately OP updated question and answer will no longer work.